# How to make a warning message if possible duplicate entry is added?

Tags: php, pdo

I have here the code for insertion using PDO and the insertion is working fine my problem is that how can i can determine if i inputted in the textbox the record that is already in the database,in my database ihave a column of ID, Firstname and Lastname, ID is auto increment,Firstname is set to unique and lastly is password set to varchar..what i want to happen is that when try to insert a record that is already in the database i want a warning message or maybe a alert message that tells me that "the record is already duplicate"..can somebody please help me with it?

**here is the code**
    ***class.php***

```
 public function create($username,$password,$province)
 {
 try
 {
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO login(Firstname,Lastname)  VALUES(:Firstname, :Lastname)");
  $stmt->bindparam(":Firstname",$Firstname);
  $stmt->bindparam(":Lastname",$Lastname);
  $stmt->execute();
  return true;

  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
  echo $e->getMessage();  
  return false;
  }
  }
```

**and here is index.php**

```
  <?php
  include_once 'dbconfig.php';

  if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))
  {
  $username = $_POST['Firstname'];
  $password = $_POST['Lastname'];

  if($crud->create($Firstname,$Lastname))
  {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Saved!');</script>";
  }
  else
  {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Insertion Failed!');  </script>";
  }  
  }
  ?>

  <form method="POST" class="signin" action="" name="Add" target="iframe">
    <fieldset class="textbox">
    <label class="username">
        <span>Username</span>
            <input id="Firstname" name="Firstname" value="" type="text" placeholder="Username" required/>
    </label>
    <label class="password">
        <span>Password</span>
            <input id="Lastname" name="Lastname" value="" type="password" Placeholder="Password" required/>
    </label>

    <br />
    <button id="submit" type="submit" name="btn-save">Save</button> 
    <button id="submit" type="reset" name="reset">Reset</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <hr>
         </fieldset>
   </form>
```

Comment: If you have the correct UNIQUE keys set in your database, PDO will already throw such a warning. You can easily try it yourself by inserting twice the same name

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge i already set the UNIQUE correctly in my database but the problem is that when i tried to save a duplicate record it just tells me "insertion failed"

Comment: Are you trying to change the text from "insertion failed" to "the record is already duplicate" ?

Comment: @ChrisDekker no.but how do i know if i already added a same record in the database without any message that tells me that i already have existing duplicate record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the correct UNIQUE keys set in your database, PDO will already throw such a warning/error. You can easily try it yourself by inserting twice the same name

You should try to change your code to this, as this will throw the actual error. The correct function to call would be [PDOStatement::errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php)

Example code would be like this:

```
public function create($username,$password,$province)
{
   try
   {
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO login(Firstname,Lastname)  VALUES(:Firstname, :Lastname)");
      $stmt->bindparam(":Firstname",$Firstname);
      $stmt->bindparam(":Lastname",$Lastname);

      if (!$stmt->execute())
      {
          throw new Exception('Could not execute SQL statement: ' . var_export($stmt->errorInfo(), TRUE));   
      }
      return true;

  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
      // Here you can filter on error messages and display a proper one.
      return $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

In your index.php, change your PHP code to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))
{
    $username = $_POST['Firstname'];
    $password = $_POST['Lastname'];

    $result = $crud->create($Firstname,$Lastname);
    if($result === TRUE)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Saved!');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(" . $result . ");  </script>";
    }  
}
```

An other, better, method would be to do a separate **SELECT** before you do the actual insert to see if the values you are trying to insert already exist.

Comment: i already tried your code but still insertion failed is always displaying..i think my problem is in this code, i think i need to something here but i don't know how..

 if($crud->create($username,$password,$province))
 {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Saved!');</script>";
  //header("Location: add-data.php?inserted");
 }
 else
 {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Insertion Failed!');</script>";
  //header("Location: add-data.php?failure");
 }  
}
?>

Comment: So you manually placed the code insertion failed there, and you are wondering why you are getting that error?

Comment: i think i should do some SELECT statement but how can i do that?

Comment: no.i put that warning "insertion failed" for me to know if my insertion is successful or not..but i want another warning or alert box that tells me if the records is already existing

Comment: I changed my code a bit. In the CATCH section you can filter on error messages to pass the correct one to your view